# Get the current position in the array on event?

Tags: jquery

I have a click event on an `ul`. With `$.inArray` I want to get the current index of the `li`. With this I can then animate the right div. My Markup is like so:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="sideways">
</div>
<div class="sideways">
</div>
```

And so on. You can swipe through the "sideways" divs and with the `ul` it's possible to also navigate to the divs through a navigation. Now my code looks like this:

```
$('.nav ul li').click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    k = $.inArray($this, $('.nav ul li'));
});
```

k always returns -1. Why does this happen? Why doesn't it return the current index?

Comment: Can't see `ul`, `li` in `.nav` in your markup. Please add related markup to your question.

Comment: Added this markup, thought I didn't need to :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the index on click why you just don't use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)?

```js
$('.nav ul li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="sideways"></div>
<div class="sideways"></div>
```

Comment: I see, I was searching for gettin the current index, and just found the .inArray function. My bad! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
var items = $('.nav ul li');

items.click(function(){
    k = items.index(this);
});
```